# Why do I get an "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException" error even though the file exists?

Tags: java, nosuchfileexception

I'm getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` but I'm sure the file exists at the given location `C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt"`.

Why do I still get this error?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadData {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
    Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt", "UTF-8"));
    int int_value;
    while ((file.hasNextInt())) {
        int_value = file.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Data:" + int_value);
    }

    file.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: "no such file" error suggests that the file you're trying to use does not exist. Do you think it does?

Comment: It occurs both VSC and Elipse IDE, And I just downloaded it yesterday. How to configed it

Comment: Umm ... look in the file system to see if there is a file at "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt".  If it doesn't exist **at that location** ... that's why your application cannot find it!   Possible solutions: 1) create the file, or 2) correct the path in your program.

Comment: I have checker, And I have inserted the exactly address file beforewards. But still it error

Comment: OK, I mistaken a problem that I cannot explain by word. Anyway Thank you very much

Comment: _OK, I mistaken a problem that I cannot explain by word. Anyway Thank you very much_ – edited your question (pending approval) to better describe your problem. Also see @DevilsHnd answer as it explains why you get this error even though your file path is correct. And don't forget to accept (and up-vote) an answer when it answers your question.

Comment: Well remove the "UTF-8" if you dont have a file named "UTF-8": 

Scanner file =new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt"));

Comment: Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt", "UTF-8") means a file with path "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt"\\UTF-8". Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your issue is with your **Paths.get()** method:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt", "UTF-8"));
```

The closing parentheses for the **Paths.get()** method is in the **wrong** place. What you are actually supplying to the Scanner object (or what the get() method interprets it to be) is a path like this:

```
"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Java.txt\UTF-8"
```

That particular path obviously **can not** be found.  It should be:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

You may want to also consider utilizing the **Try With Resources** mechanism. It will auto-close the file reader:

```
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Java.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
    int int_value;
    while ((file.hasNextInt())) {
        int_value = file.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Data:" + int_value);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just keep the text file in your project folder and simply change the code like below

`Scanner file=new Scanner(new File("Java.txt"));`
hope it will solve your issue